# Question on quotient set.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations, equivalence-relations

[image]

Above is a problem from my end sem mathematics question paper.

**In this question I have two basic problems or else I have not understood the question properly**

1. Notation A/R is used for quotient set(till now I only know this), each element of a quotient set is itself a set. Now it is given that A/R = P, if A is a set whose elements are not sets then P being a subset of A will also have elements which are not set, which contradicts the property of a quotient set. **Basically I have problem in understanding what is the meaning of A/R=P?**
2. Let us ignore the notion as asked above. I assume that A/R=P means that the quotient set contains the equivalence class of elements belonging to set P.

Let A={1,2,3} and let P={2,3}

There is a theorem which states that if we partition any non-empty A, then we can define an equivalence relation on A such that each partition will be an equivalence class. So now clearly the A/R will contain the equivalence class of element '1' then A/R $\ne$ P. This means that there exists no such R. This again shows that the question is wrong.

**Above are the two confusions, please check it and clear my doubts. If I'm understanding the question wrong then please make me understand the question clearly.**

Thank you!

Comment: If $A = \{ 1,2,3\}$ then $P = \{ \{ 1\} , \{2,3\}\}$ is a partition of $A$.  A partition $P$ is a set of subsets of $A$ with certain properties. Think about the definition of partition more carefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every equivalence relation $R$ on $A$, the quotient $A/R$ is the set of $R$-equivalance classes $[x]$ of elements $x \in A$. Here, $[x]=\{y\in A\,|\,yRx\}$ is the set of elements of $A$ that are equivalent to $x$ (under $R$).

Now, a *partition* $P$ of a set $A$ is a collection of disjoint subsets $\mathcal{A}_k$ of $A$ whose union is $A$. In symbols, $P=\{\mathcal{A}_k\,|\,k\in I\}$, $\mathcal{A}_j\cap\mathcal{A}_k=\emptyset$ whenever $j\neq k$ and $\cup_{k\in I}\mathcal{A}_k=A$. Here, $I$ is some arbitrary index set.

When one writes $A/R=P$ it means that each equivalence class $[x] \in A/R$ corresponds to one of the $\mathcal{A}_k$'s in $P$.

Can you think of something that relates equivalence relations and partitions?

Answer (score 0):

A partition of a set is a set of sets. A quotient of a set is a set of sets. The meaning of $A/R = P$ is set equality.

You said:
"if A is a set whose elements are not sets".
Everything is a set in set theory.

Moreover, if $A=\{1,2,3\}$ then $P=\{2,3\}$ is not a partition.

I recommend reflecting on these things more instead of trying to do exercises. Try to think of what a partition means to you.